# Search data from Realm jammed the main thread

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I got an old project that has a local record search algorithm based on Realm database.

The main thread will be jammed when the search began in the database that has thousands of records.

It can't be switched to other threads since the existed Realm database created and run on the main thread.

Is there anyone knows how to solve this jam problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
# The search algorithm is actually only applied a filter on the objects array.

# data is all items in database

data = realm.objects(CustomObject.self).filter(filterPredicate(parentID: id, keyword: keyword, colorIndex: colorIndexes, isActionOnly: True)).sorted(by: descSorting)


private func filterPredicate(parentID: Int?, keyword: String?, colorIndex: [Int]?, isActionOnly: Bool = false) -> InspirationFilterClosure {
    return { item in
        if item.isDeleted { return false }
        if let id = parentID, item.parentID != id { return false }
        else if item.parentID < 0 { return false }
        if isActionOnly, !item.isAction  { return false }
        if let indexes = colorIndex, !indexes.contains(-1), !indexes.contains(item.colorIndex) { return false }
        if let keyword = keyword, !keyword.isEmpty {
            return item.content.range(of: keyword, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the code of search algorithm ? before the filtering stuff.

Comment: try to run this func async..DispatchQueue.main.async { call func here }

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati it just simply loaded by `data = realm.objects(CustomObject.self)`

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed But the problem is it takes time to finish the search, like 2 seconds. Anyway, it will block the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to avoid Jamming of main Thread

- You have to use this concept  [ThreadSafeReference](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads) which is mentioned in the documentation.
- You can use Realm [Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications) concept to observe your fetched objects in background thread.

> **Suggestions**: Please go through above concepts and try to implement it on your own. if you still face any issue, do let us know.